# maven - can two modules use different versions of the same library

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a java project with two maven modules (moduleA and moduleB), where each module want to access different versions (v1 and v2) of the same library. moduleA uses moduleB as a dependency. I created moduleB mainly to get around this problem and also thought it will keep the code well organized.

I have used maven shade plugin in moduleA's pom.xml, thinking it will help me differentiate the classes from each version but i still get "NoSuchMethodError" even though that method is available in v2 version of the library. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't have 2 versions of your library at run-time. If it's not compatible, you need to choose a version and stick with it.

Comment: Look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827335/different-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-maven

Comment: you will have to use Maven-Shade-Plugin to rename the packages of the library in either moduleA or moduleB. Will only work if the library does not use Reflection or similar to access its own classes.

Comment: @mihi can you guide me how to do it ? I tried using `<relocation><pattern>org.library</pattern><shadedPattern>org.library_v2</shadedPattern></relocation>` under maven-shade-plugin in moduleB's pom.xml. as i wanted this version to be renamed. but i am still facing issues.

Comment: Check the generated artifacts. Make sure that org.library_v2 gets packaged into the shaded artifact jar and that you do not depend on org.library Version 2 in your generated artifact POM (or it will include the unshaded version in the final classpath, making moduleA break).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can work: There's going to be namespace clash if you try to load two different versions of the same library into Java at one time